# saving as pdf from Rstudio

Tags: r, pdf, plot

so I want add some charm to my plots by changing the fonts. But my RStudio always crashes as I try to save as a pdf. So lets take this data:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type="n")
windowsFonts(
  A=windowsFont("Arial Black"),
  B=windowsFont("Bookman Old Style"),
  C=windowsFont("Comic Sans MS"),
  D=windowsFont("Symbol")
)
text(3,3,"Hello World Default")
text(4,4,family="A","Hello World from Arial Black")
text(5,5,family="B","Hello World from Bookman Old Style")
text(6,6,family="C","Hello World from Comic Sans MS")
text(7,7,family="D", "Hello World from Symbol")
```

Then using the `Export`>>`Save as pdf` function, the image with the different fonts will not save. Also using the  `pdf("SampleGraph.pdf",width=7,height=5)`
Does not work. Doesnt anyone know of a way around this issue, or is it my computer got out of the wrong side of bed today?

Comment: Have you done a search already or is this your first stop? Maybe start [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=save%20as%20pdf%20r&es_th=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `.pdf` format cannot handle those fonts. One solution would be to export the image as a `.png` format and use **Sweave** to include the figure in the `.pdf`. Alternatively, you could convert the `.png` to a `.pdf` using a program such as Foxit Reader or ImageMagick. I'll demonstrate the **Sweave** solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
par(mar=c(3,3,3,3))
png("test.png", units="in", width=8, height=8, res=500)
plot(1:10,1:10,type="n",xlab="",ylab="")
windowsFonts(
    A=windowsFont("Arial Black"),
    B=windowsFont("Bookman Old Style"),
    C=windowsFont("Comic Sans MS"),
    D=windowsFont("Symbol")
)
text(3,3,"Hello World Default")
text(4,4,family="A","Hello World from Arial Black")
text(5,5,family="B","Hello World from Bookman Old Style")
text(6,6,family="C","Hello World from Comic Sans MS")
text(7,7,family="D", "Hello World from Symbol") 
x <- dev.off()
@

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following `.pdf` file.

[image]